# Why my texture can't show up in full screen mode DX11 game

Tags: fullscreen, directx-11

I'm drawing a texture in a DX11 game. It's strange that the texture never shows up in the full screen mode.

I list my state setting here for reference.

```
BOOL BlendEnable[] = {TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE};
UINT8 RenderTargetWriteMask[] = {0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF};

D3D11_BLEND_DESC  bs11 = {0};
bs11.AlphaToCoverageEnable = 0;
bs11.IndependentBlendEnable = false;

for(size_t i = sizeof(BlendEnable) / sizeof(BlendEnable[0]); i--;)
{
     bs11.RenderTarget[i].BlendEnable = BlendEnable[i];
     bs11.RenderTarget[i].RenderTargetWriteMask = RenderTargetWriteMask[i];
}

bs11.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_OP_ADD;
bs11.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_OP_ADD;
bs11.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
bs11.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_ZERO;
bs11.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
bs11.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D10_DDI_BLEND_ONE;       
bs11.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D10_DDI_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthDesc;
depthDesc.DepthEnable = 0;
depthDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D10_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO;
depthDesc.DepthFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_NEVER;
depthDesc.BackEnable = 0;
depthDesc.FrontEnable = 0;
depthDesc.StencilEnable = 0;
depthDesc.StencilReadMask = 0;
depthDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0;
depthDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_DDI_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_DDI_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_DDI_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
```

What's the most likely issue it can be?

Thanks,
Marshall

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issues but the D3D11_BLEND_DESC/D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC variables are being set as D3D10_ flags as far as I know this usually compiles but should be the D3D11_ equivalent.

So the texture shows under windowed mode?

Comment: Well I asked about windowed mode because if its not showing up in either windowed or fullscreen then more information about the vertexbuffer/drawing information is needed.

Are you getting any warnings from the debug device?

Lastly did you mean to edit my post, I think you meant to add comment which you can since its your question.

Comment: I might also suggest using nvidia parallel nsight if you have an nvidia card as it allows you to see step by step the draw calls. Visually I prefer it to PIX as it'll outline triangles if they are in view.    
(Pix is a debugger provided in the directx sdk. Which you can also use to see whats happening in shaders/directx api)


Also arrrgh comments removing line spacing, sorry about that.